# Find Error Codes in .TXT file

Tags: batch, batch-file

I'm a newbie to the coding world, can someone help me with below scenario?

I need a batch script for windows that does the following:

Scan *.txt file in the “Input” folder to find if there are any “Error codes” like **503**, **504**, **511** and **611** (scenario mentioned below);

Below is the sample .txt file where every 1st row has no data and can be ignored; the following rows has data where the batch should scan and find the error codes (if any) between 18-20 characters only, each row has 90 characters including spaces.

> H0001200008143800120918155209
>   D43442371013477773520000001280012091800001
>   D4344237101172222**511**0000000900012091800001
>   D4344237100769292**504**0000007200012091800001

If any .txt file has the above-mentioned error codes then that file should not be moved to “Verified” Folder if no error codes are found then the .txt file should be moved to "Verified" folder.

Comment: Does it have to be a batch file, or would a Powershell script command suffice?

Comment: @helpinghand powershell script would be fine too

Comment: Is the error code always 3 digits and 17 chars from the first character of each line?

Comment: @sonamon Yes, the error code will be 3 digit always and 18th character from the  first character of each line.

Comment: Will the line that has the error in always starts with letter D?

Comment: all rows except the 1st row will have letter "D"

Comment: Please see my answer.

Comment: I had to do a few edits as I missed some parts of your question.

Comment: Depending on the size and number of files you are searching in this particular case, I think a pure batch script would perform poorly but I can think in my head of a way to try to handle this for a starting test point at least. It sounds like you are `1.` searching contents of multiple files in a directory, `2.` searching at specific line positions for each line of each file, `3.` and verify if there are any matches of any strings from a list of codes in an error list or whatever. I definitely have pure batch ideas but depending on size and scale, it may not  be too efficient and serialized.

Answer (score 1):

This should work in Powershell. It reads the first letter of each line if it's not D it won't check it for an error code.

If the line starts with the letter D it will read between the 17th and 20th character and outputs the error codes if it is 503, 504, 511 or 611. Hope this helps.

```
$content = Get-Content -path C:\USERS\path\to\codes.txt
foreach ($line in $content)
 {
   $firstLetter = $line.Substring(0,1)

    if ($firstLetter -eq "D")
     {
       $errorCode = $line.Substring(17,3)
       switch ($errorCode)
       {
          '503'
         {
           Write-host $errorCode
         }
         '504'
         {
           Write-host $errorCode
         }
         '511'
         {
           Write-host $errorCode
         }
         '611'
         {
           Write-host $errorCode
         }
       }
     }
  }
```

My input was a txt file containing

```
H0001200008143800120918155209
D43442371013477773520000001280012091800001
D43442371011722225110000000900012091800001
D43442371007692925040000007200012091800001
```

The output of the script is

```
511
504
```

Comment: thanks @Sonamon for the quick solution, i also want to know if any of the files does not have 503, 504, 511 or 611 error codes will that file be sent to "Verified" folder and if any of the file has error codes will remain in the same folder?

Comment: I could easily do that for you but then I will get all the fun out of learning powershell @user9749652 . Please try to implement this yourself and you have any issues please tag me :)

Comment: @user9749652 - If you look at [this link](https://ss64.com/ps/switch.html), it should be obvious how to modify the answer by adding `break` to each `switch` case, and specifying a `default` clause.

Comment: @Sonamor :) sure, i will try to this atleast, thank you for your help.

Comment: @user9749652 the information that AFH provided should be more than enough to finish your script and to do exactly what you want :). If you need help tag me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a FOR loop to iterate the .txt files, and use FINDSTR to test each file if it contains one of the 4 errors, and conditionally move the file if the search string is not found. The regular expression capabilities are fairly crippled, so the search is more complicated than it ought to be.

I'm not at a Windows machine at the moment, so I can't test, but the following should work, unless I have some silly bug that should be easily fixed.

```
@echo off
set local
set "beg=^D................"
for %%F in (input\*.txt) do findstr /r "%beg%503 %beg%504 %beg%511 %beg%611" "%%F" >nul || move "%%F" verified
```

Comment: @Sonamor, I tried the below code and it is failing;

Comment: @ dbenham, the batch does moves all the files including the one which has error codes too

Comment: @user9749652 - I was finally able to test, and it worked for me. Are you sure the D of each error line is at the very beginning of the line? Because that is what my test data looks like. If I copy the sample data from the quote in your question, then the D is in position 2, which of course causes my solution to fail. Let me know if the first character of an error line should be space, which will require a change to my solution.

Comment: @user9749652 - Also, are there really only 4 error codes that you need to worry about? If there are more than 4, then you need to list them all, or else do a better job at specifying how to recognize them.

Comment: @ Dbenham, Are you sure the D of each error line is at the very beginning of the line? **Yes** and in that line the error code position is between 18,19,20 characters.

Comment: @ Dbenham, currently there are only 4 error codes.

Comment: @user9749652 - I don't know what to say then. The code works perfectly for me - only files without errors are moved to the verify folder when I run the code.